# Rails 3, Cucumber, Capybara cannot select element / render complete html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, bdd, capybara

A cucumber feature keeps failing because capybara does not render the whole html as intended

here is the feature

```
When I select my "Test Cluster" from "Cluster Selection"
```

and the step definition

```
When /^I select my "(.*)" from "(.*)"$/ do |field, value|
  fill_in(field, :with => value)
end
```

It should pass, but cucumber/capybara keeps complaining that it cannot find the dropdown with the label "Cluster Selection"

So I went into debugger mode and ran cucumber

```
When /^I select my "(.*)" from "(.*)"$/ do |field, value|
  debugger
  fill_in(field, :with => value)
end
```

What I found was that when I type

```
pp page.body
```

all it returns is the HTML doc declaration. It's missing the `<head>` and `<body>`, so no wonder it cant find the dropdown.

Anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: The page renders correctly in development?